# number of possible correspondences

Tags: combinatorics

I have two sets $A$, $B$ with $|A|$ > $|B|$ and I need to find all the possible ways to establish exactly $k=3$ correspondences. The order of the correspondences does not matter.
Here is an example with $Y_i$ one possible correspondence:

$A=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $B=\{w,x,y,z\}$

-> $Y_1 = \{(a,w),(b,x), (c,y) \}$, $Y_2 = \{(a,w),(b,x), (c,z) \}$ ...

Is there a method to do this efficiently and how can I count the number of possible correspondences?

I am glad for any hint. Thanks!

Comment: ${|A|\choose3}\cdot{|B|\choose3}$ ?

Comment: Do you want to pick $k$ distinct items from each set and pair them up? Or are duplicates allowed?

Comment: exactly, I can only take each item once. e.g. $Y = \{(a,w),(a,x),(c,y)\}$ is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $k$ distinct items from each set, and there are $k!$ ways to make $k$ correspondences between them (hold one set of selected items and permute the other set). The answer is $\binom{|A|}{k}\binom{|B|}{k}k!$.